# Pandas increment integer at certain index points?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a list of integers which correspond to points where I want to increase an interger value by 1.

for example `Int64Index([5, 10])`, not necessarily even spaced like that, and I have a dataframe like,

```
    val          new_col
0   0.729726564  1
1   0.067509062  1
2   0.943927114  1
3   0.037718436  1
4   0.512142908  1
5   0.767198655  2
6   0.202230787  2
7   0.343767479  2
8   0.540026305  2
9   0.256425022  2
10  0.403845023  3
11  0.444475008  3
12  0.464677745  3
```

I want to create `new_col` which is an int, but increases by on a the above index rows.

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.rand(14)})
df['new_col'] = 1
```

How to increase the value of `new_col` by one at each index point `(5, 10)`?

Comment: Can you show a minimally viable example?  Not sure what the starting point is and what the desired result is supposed to be.

Comment: I can't see how that `Int64Index` relates to the values in `new_col`. If you want an increment every 5 elements: `df['new_col'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 5 + 1`

Comment: I was just using those as a reference, they my not be evenly spaced, e.g. 5 one group, 4 another group.  Basically, I want to increase the value of new_col by on at some arbitrary position.

Comment: I had a similar outstanding question regarding creating a non evenly spaced arange, which I used as my solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469267/create-non-evenly-randomly-spaced-arange-from-a-list-of-index-positions/57474766#57474766

Answer (score 1):

I see from your comment that you refer to an "arbitrary position" so you can space them as you wish with [bins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html).

example:

```
bins = [-1,3,5,12,14] #space as you wish
labels = [1,2,3,4] #labels or in your case values that you want

df['new_col'] = pd.cut(list(df.index.values), bins=bins, labels=labels)


val new_col
0   0.509742    1
1   0.081701    1
2   0.990583    1
3   0.813398    1
4   0.905022    2
5   0.951973    2
6   0.702487    3
7   0.916432    3
8   0.647568    3
9   0.955188    3
10  0.875067    3
11  0.284496    3
12  0.393931    3
13  0.341115    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.split` with `enumerate`:

```
import pandas as pd

indices = [5, 10]
df['add_col'] = pd.concat([s + n for n, s in enumerate(pd.np.split(df['new_col'], indices))])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         val  new_col  add_col
0   0.953431        1        1
1   0.929134        1        1
2   0.548343        1        1
3   0.080713        1        1
4   0.465212        1        1
5   0.290549        1        2
6   0.570886        1        2
7   0.232350        1        2
8   0.036968        1        2
9   0.455084        1        2
10  0.385177        1        3
11  0.811477        1        3
12  0.802502        1        3
13  0.001847        1        3
```