# create non evenly (randomly) spaced arange from a list of index positions?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a array on ones and a list of positions:

```
arr = np.ones(35)
[3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19, 25, 27, 33]
```

At these various points, I want to increase by one so that I have a final array that is something like

```
array([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,....])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
arr = np.ones(35)
idx = [3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19, 25, 27, 33]
for val in idx:
    arr[val:] = arr[val:] + 1
```

(For those unfamilar with Python indexing, the notation `[val:]` simply indexes from `val` to the end of the array.)

The output then is:

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  5.,
        5.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  7.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  9.,
        9., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 11., 11.])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = np.zeros(35, dtype=int)
idx = [3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19, 25, 27, 33]
arr[0] = 1
arr[idx] = 1
result = arr.cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repeat` with `ediff1d`.

```
arr = np.array([3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19, 25, 27, 33])
res = np.repeat(
    np.arange(1, arr.shape[0] + 1), 
    np.ediff1d(arr, to_begin=arr[0])
)

# array([ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,
#         7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

This has a flexibility of choosing the first argument to `repeat`:

```
In [81]: np.repeat( 
    ...:     [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29],  
    ...:     np.ediff1d(arr, to_begin=arr[0]) 
    ...: )                                                               
Out[81]: 
array([ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  5,  5,  5,  7,  7,  7,  7, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13,
       17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 23, 23, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `np.searchsorted`:

```
size = 35
idx = [3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19, 25, 27, 33]
result = np.searchsorted(idx, np.arange(size), side='right') + 1
```